# ReentrantLock with priorities for waiting threads

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I am trying to have a `ReentrantLock` with another way to determinate which thread will have the lock in the waiting queue. `ReentrantLock` implementation manages a Fair/Unfair policy, that's not what I want.

I would like to give a priority when I call the `.lock()` method, and this priority will determinate the order of current thread in the waiting threads queue.

I wrote a class, based on a `PriorityBlockingQueue`, and I'd like your opinion.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;

/**
 * Class to lock a resource. 
 * When multiple threads are waiting for the resource to be unlocked, the one with the greatest priority will have the resource.
 * When two threads have the same priority, the first added thread will lock the resource.
 *
 */
public class PrioritizedLock {

  private PriorityBlockingQueue<PrioritizedThread> waitingQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<PrioritizedThread>();

  private volatile PrioritizedThread activeThread;

  private volatile Object syncStartNext = new Object();

  private volatile boolean shutdown = false;

  public PrioritizedLock() {
    startQueueWatcher();
  }

  /**
   * Starts a queue watcher, which takes PrioritizedThread from the PriorityBlockingQueue and notify them to wake them up.
   */
  private void startQueueWatcher() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (!shutdown) {

          /*
           * Wait until a PrioritizedThread is added to the PriorityBlockingQueue
           */
          while (activeThread == null) {
            try {
              activeThread = waitingQueue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
              //
            }
          }

          /*
           * Notify the thread to wake up (now it has locked the resource) 
           */
          synchronized (activeThread) {
            activeThread.notify();
          }

          /*
           * Wait until the resource has been released from the active thread
           */
          while (activeThread != null) {
            synchronized (syncStartNext) {
              try {
                syncStartNext.wait();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //
              }
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }).start();
  }

  /**
   * Waits until the thread is woken up by the Queue Watcher thread
   * @param thread
   */
  private void wait(PrioritizedThread thread) {
    synchronized (thread) {

      while (activeThread != thread) {
        try {
          thread.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          //
        }

      }
    }

  }

  static class PrioritizedThread implements Comparable<PrioritizedThread> {
    Thread thread;

    int priority;

    Date date = new Date();

    public PrioritizedThread(Thread aThread, int aPriority) {
      thread = aThread;
      priority = aPriority;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PrioritizedThread other) {
      int diffPriorities = this.priority - other.priority;

      if (diffPriorities == 0) {
        return date.compareTo(other.date);
      }
      return diffPriorities;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Waits until the resource is locked by the current thread
   * @param priority Priority of the lock, the less has the greatest priority
   */
  public void lock(int priority) {
    PrioritizedThread prioritizedThread = new PrioritizedThread(Thread.currentThread(), priority);

    waitingQueue.add(prioritizedThread);
    wait(prioritizedThread);
  }

  /**
   * Unlock the resource
   */
  public void unlock() {
    activeThread = null;

    synchronized (syncStartNext) {
      syncStartNext.notify();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Trigger a shutdown of the lock,
   */
  public void shutdown() {
    shutdown = true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

After calling shutdown(), the shutdown boolean may never get checked. The Thread may be stuck in waitingQueue.take().

It's probably not a good idea to catch and swallow InterruptedException.

Considering those two points together, it makes sense to remove the Thread and use [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) instead, and delegate to its [shutdown()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) method.

Finally, it's fairly low-level and error prone to use wait() and notifyAll(). Using notify() is even riskier than notifyAll(). I'd recommend using a [Condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) instead.